# Ionic: background-image not applying correctly

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, background

I have a (long) page with ion-list and many ion-scroll in ion-grid. I'm trying to apply a background image to this page in particular. It's working perfectly on another page (with less html)

sample.html:

```
<ion-content no-padding overflow-scroll="true" class="test">
 <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="refreshHome($event)">
   <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
 </ion-refresher>
 <img [src]="banner.png"/>
 <ion-list class="category_list" *ngIf="tags_home && tags_home[0]">
   <div *ngFor='let tag_selected of tags_home' class="category">
    <ion-grid no-padding align-items: center>
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col>title
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col col-auto>
          <button>button</button>
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
    <ion-scroll scrollX="true" direction="x">
      <img *ngFor="let item of tag_selected.slide" [src]="item.img"/>
    </ion-scroll>
```

sample.css:

```
  ion-content {
   .category_list {
     bottom: 0;
     height: 62vh;
     .category { ... }
    }
  }
```

I tried adding `background-image` under `ion-content` (and ion-list) but nothing is showing up (working on other pages without any problem). Adding the background under `.category_list` only show it for about 30% of the page (it stop before even scrolling).

Inspecting the css in Chrome inspector, I added a `scroll-content` class with `background-image`. The whole page showed the background but every ion-scroll had its *own* background as well...

I tried using the `:not()` but failed (either no background at all, no result or lost the background-size on the 'real' background)

<s>I'm pretty sure the ion-scrolls are messing with my background because they are not present on the other page.</s>

Edit: It wasn't in my sample to avoid cluttering but I have an `ion-refresh` before my banner... This ion-refresh **does** have the background when it is placed under `ion-content`. Deleting it correctly show the background on the whole page. But I need this `ion-refresh`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved it...

```
  ion-content {
   .scroll-content {
     background-image: url('../assets/imgs/sample.png');
     background-repeat: repeat !important;
     background-size: 120% !important;
   }
```

This way, the `ion-refresh` isn't <s>eating</s> hiding my background. But every `ion-scroll` had a background too. So I selected every `scroll-content` under the `.category` class.

```
ion-content {
  .scroll-content {
     background-image: url('../assets/imgs/sample.png');
     background-repeat: repeat !important;
     background-size: 120% !important;
   }
  .category_list {
    //...
    .category {
      .scroll-content {
        background-image: none !important;
      }
      //...
    }
```

And everything is working fine with that combinaison.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your background for `<ion-content>` like this,

```
<ion-content padding style="background-image:url('your-img-path/url');background-position: center;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">
```

Comment: it wasn't in my sample to avoid cluttering but I have an `ion-refresh` before my banner... This ion-refresh **does** have the background. Deleting it, correctly show the background on the whole page. But I need this `ion-refresh`...